# Connecting to a TFS server closes a Git solution

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2013, git-tfs

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 with the new built-in Git support. Our project is managed in TFS 2010, but because of inertia/stubbornness, I use [git-tfs](http://git-tfs.com) for source control. I still use the TFS issue tracker etc.

In VS2012, this worked fine - VS just saw the solution as not being under any supported source control, and let me work with TFS work items just fine. In VS2013 however, the project is detected as being managed under Git. This makes VS's TFS integration pretty much unavailable.

This means that I'm not connected to the team project when working on my solution. When I connect to TFS, the solution gets closed. Vice versa - reopening the Git-managed solution closes any work item queries I had open and disconnects me from TFS.

Is there any way to work around this? Disabling the built-in Git support, or a setting I missed?

Comment: Same thing with VS2012 and "Visual Studio Tools for Git" extension (which is VS2013 : the extension is bundle with it) and was enable to manage the case. I was obliged to uninstall the extension :( I don't know a solution for that...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[VS Team is aware of the problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/10/30/visual-studio-2012-tools-for-git-rtm.aspx?CommentPosted=true#10463840) :

> Allowing users to disable the automatic provider switching is something we're considering.  When we added Git support, we thought about Git-TF users and optimized for using the developers wanting to use the Git tools.  The side effect is that you can't easily work with the TFS team project.

Comment: This is an odd stance to take, since even Git-TF users would probably need to deal with TFS work items. (Obviously there's always the web interface, but that doesn't have the convenience of being a keyboard shortcut away.) Although I suppose I should make this comment on that blog not here.

Comment: Anyway, if no workaround surfaces by tomorrow I'll accept this as a "this is broken by design" answer.