# Possible to use git project AND see TFS work items in VS2013?

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013, git-tfs

So I've upgraded to VS2013, hopefully for all development. One thing really irks me about it though. My team uses TFS, and I prefer git, so I use git-tfs to bridge the two for source control. We use TFS work items for tracking of bugs and stories and such. I prefer GitExtensions to the built-in git support of VS2013 as well, if it matters.

Anyway, When I have a solution open that's under a git-tfs repository, VS2013 will helpfully only show me options for git under the Team Explorer tab. So, when I want to go to a TFS work item query, I have to do Connect Team Project > FooProject, or some such.. VS2013 at this point, very helpfully will close my open solutiopn. So, basically I can't view work items and have a solution open in VS2013 at the same time. This seems like a gross design oversight.

Is there anyway to view work item queries within an instance of VS2013 with a git project open and/or is it possible to just disable Visual Studio 2013's git support altogether, since I prefer GitExtensions anyway?

Comment: VS2013 git support is pretty horrible, I think that the only way to properly work with git in VS is GitExtensions. Why anyone would ever want to stage or commit in VS when you have GitExtensions by-line staging window I don't know.

Comment: @Wilbert I agree with your point of view but that's not the problem here. We are Ok to use another soft to manage git stuff but, here, it's to manage TFS stuff (workitems, tasks,...) where the problem is. When VS detect a git repository, it close the connexion to the TFS server!

Comment: I ended up using another VS instance (VS2012 actually) connected to TFS for work item tracking and process related stuff while coding in VS2013. Commiting with VS2013 is OK, but I also have a git-bash+gitk running where VS2013 git support fails.

Answer (score 2):

As already said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19791321) that's not possible :( I have warned Microsoft about that and that's on their todo list. But when will it be done? We don't know...

For the moment I think that you should use the Web portal...

edit: someone find a way to [remove the VS Git plugin](http://blog.markrendle.net/2014/03/27/disable-the-git-source-control-add-in-in-vs2013-permanently/). He delete keys in the registry. I highly advice to export theses keys before deleting them in the case you want to restore them in the future!

Answer (score 1):

To avoid having to keep an instance of Visual Studio open just for TFS workitems, I disabled TFS solution integration. This disabled both TFS and Git source control options for solutions, but TFS work items still work fine.

You can disable it by do this:

1. Tools
2. Options
3. Source Control
4. Change current source control plugin from TFS to None

Comment: Turns out this isn't a permanent fix either. When I open a solution after doing this, it returns to using git integration. ugh.