# Benefits of Git vs TFS

Tags: git

I've noticed a buzz word "we should use Git for TFS". My understanding is that Git is just DVCS.

TFS support everything from branching, labelling, merging, checking in, checking out, shelving, etc.

Could someone please help me understand under what scenarios should team use Git or TFS?

Apart from local repository and distributed, what other benefits can it provide to the team?

Does it have better support of branching and merging? From what I've seen developer can create new branches on his/her local repository, which I think should make more hard to manage branches.

Any suggestions will be good.

Comment: Too broad and offtopic.

Comment: Speed. Seriously, don't underestimate it as a benefit. It completely changes how you see code. For example, with Git merging 6 times a day is painless. That doesn't mean that people using git merge 6 or 10 times a day but the thought of doing that doesn't scare people as much as with other source control software. Once branches don't scare you anymore then there's no need to "manage" all branches. Another example is debugging, because of it's speed you will start using git more and more as a tool to read code (find out why the code was written that way).

Comment: comparing Git to TFS is like comparing an editor to an IDE. An IDE _is_ an editor but depending on your point of view either a) a very bloated one that's too slow b) a feature rich editor that does more things than _just_ an editor. All the benefits you mention for TFS are things Git does (very, very well).

Comment: Incidentally it's funny to see Git referred to as Gits

Answer (score 2):

> TFS support everything from branching, labelling, merging, checkin, checkout, shelve etc.

Those are features that any VCS (Version Control System) does support. Git supports those as well (shelve is called [`git stash`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash): see "[what's the Git equivalent of TFS commands shelve/unshelve? cherry-pick?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3069979/6309)" and "[`git stash` equivalents in other revision control systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3272973/6309)").

As I explained in "[In what ways is Mercurial better/worse than TFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4104296/6309)", TFS is a ALM (Application Lifecycle Management) tool, with tickets, reporting, project tracking and more), in addition of the simple VCS features.

See also "[Which version control system should I use?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181368.aspx#tfvc_or_git_summary)", mentioned in "[Git vs TFVC Source Control](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20107701/6309)".

With [offers like git-tf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12147517/6309), you  can integrate Git to TFS anyway.
[VS2013 supports Git as well](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GitSupportForVisualStudioGitTFSAndVSPutIntoContext.aspx), although you need to [tweak it to view the TFS work items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20065677/6309).

> Things start getting interesting if one could have Git as their source control with Team Foundation on the backend for ALM tools.